# Makefile that is a wrapper for a package.json & docker-compose files

Tags: makefile

I've got the following Makefile..

```
.PHONY: install install-prod clean

MODULE := ./node_modules/.bin
COMPOSE := docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml

install:
    @echo "--- Installing dependencies!"
    npm install

install-prod:
    @echo "--- Installing production dependencies!"
    npm install --only=production

build:
    @echo "--- Babelify-ing code!"
    npm run build

run:
    @echo "--- Building Docker and running app!"
    ${COMPOSE} up --build -d app

test:
    @echo "--- Running tests"
    npm run test

coverall:
    @echo "--- Running tests & reporting to Coverall!"
    npm run coverall

clear:
    @echo "--- Clearing everything!"
    ${COMPOSE} down
```

It's a simple one, but in essence, it wraps commands in a `package.json` and a `docker-compose.yml` for an `express` app so it makes calls in a `CI Pipeline` easier to understand and maintain.

Would love some feedback about whether it can be optimized, cleaner, or potentially smaller. Anything really :)